# installing packages with oldest dependencies

Tags: debian, software-installation, dependencies, skype

System : Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) 64-bit

uname -r : 4.9.0-0.bpo.1-amd64

Well I updated kernel to 4.9. And updated all my packages. But now I'm trying to install skype and gtk3 library, and I get dependencies problem.
In order to install skype I do this:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo aptitude update
wget -O skype-install.deb http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb
sudo dpkg -i skype-install.deb
```

Well and I end up with

```
 skype:i386 : Depends: libqt4-dbus:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqt4-network:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqt4-xml:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.1.0~2011week13) but it is not installed
              Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.2.1) but it is not installed
              Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libxss1:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libxv1:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libpulse0:i386 but it is not installed
              Depends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f
```

if I try apt-get -f install it will suggest to delete skype and that it. I tried aptitude, but also without result. And yes I'm already did apt-get update && apt-get install.

When I'm trying to install libgtk3 I got:

```
libgtk-3-dev : Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

Aptitude got me that :

```
libdbus-1-dev : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (= 1.8.22-0+deb8u1) but 1.10.14-1 is installed.
```

Well I thought that since I have newest library, I can force to install it older version to fix the dependencies problem but I got that :

```
 sudo aptitude install libdbus-1-3=1.8.22-0
Unable to find a version "1.8.22-0" for the package "libdbus-1-3"
```

I don't know what to do, it's not allowing me to install older libraries, and don't work with new ones. I search a lot about it, but all the problems was solved with apt-get update and install. How I can install this package?

//-------------

sudo apt-cache policy

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ testing/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ testing/main Translation-en
 500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ testing/contrib Translation-en
-500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ testing/non-free i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin httpredir.debian.org
-500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ testing/contrib i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin httpredir.debian.org
-500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ testing/main i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main
     origin httpredir.debian.org
-500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ testing/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin httpredir.debian.org
-500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ testing/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin httpredir.debian.org
-500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main
     origin httpredir.debian.org
 500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie-backports/main Translation-en
 100 http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie-backports/main i386 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=jessie-backports,n=jessie-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main
     origin http.debian.net
 100 http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=jessie-backports,n=jessie-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main
     origin http.debian.net
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/non-free i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/contrib i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/main i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main Translation-en
 100 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main i386 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=jessie-backports,n=jessie-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main
     origin ftp.debian.org
 100 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=jessie-backports,n=jessie-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main
     origin ftp.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-proposed-updates/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-proposed-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-proposed-updates/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-proposed-updates/non-free i386 Packages
     release v=8-updates,o=Debian,a=proposed-updates,n=jessie-proposed-updates,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-proposed-updates/contrib i386 Packages
     release v=8-updates,o=Debian,a=proposed-updates,n=jessie-proposed-updates,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-proposed-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=8-updates,o=Debian,a=proposed-updates,n=jessie-proposed-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-proposed-updates/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=8-updates,o=Debian,a=proposed-updates,n=jessie-proposed-updates,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-proposed-updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=8-updates,o=Debian,a=proposed-updates,n=jessie-proposed-updates,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-proposed-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=8-updates,o=Debian,a=proposed-updates,n=jessie-proposed-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en
 990 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/non-free i386 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=non-free
     origin security.debian.org
 990 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/contrib i386 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=contrib
     origin security.debian.org
 990 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 990 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=non-free
     origin security.debian.org
 990 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=contrib
     origin security.debian.org
 990 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/contrib Translation-en
 990 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/non-free i386 Packages
     release v=8.7,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 990 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/contrib i386 Packages
     release v=8.7,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 990 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main i386 Packages
     release v=8.7,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 990 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=8.7,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 990 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=8.7,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 990 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
     release v=8.7,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```

My source list:

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.6.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20160917-14:20]/ jessie main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.6.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20160917-14:20]/ jessie main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-proposed-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
```

also It seam to me something wrong here :

```
dpkg -l  |awk '/^ii/ && $3 ~ /bpo[6-8]/ {print $2}'

libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
libllvm3.8:amd64
linux-compiler-gcc-4.9-x86
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-686-pae
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-all
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-all-amd64
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-common
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-common-rt
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-rt-686-pae
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-rt-amd64
mesa-vulkan-drivers
```

//output of sudo apt-show-versions | grep testing 
Well not expected to see so many packages, I just need a newest intell driver in order to work with vulkan.

```
bash-completion:all/testing 1:2.1-4.3 uptodate
binutils:amd64/testing 2.27.90.20170124-2 uptodate
console-setup:all/testing *manually* upgradeable from 1.158 to 1.160
console-setup-linux:all/testing *manually* upgradeable from 1.158 to 1.160
dbus:amd64/testing *manually* upgradeable from 1.10.14-1 to 1.10.16-1
flashplugin-nonfree:amd64/testing 1:3.7 uptodate
ifupdown:amd64/testing 0.8.19 uptodate
init-system-helpers:all/testing 1.47 uptodate
kbd:amd64/testing 2.0.3-2 uptodate
keyboard-configuration:all/testing *manually* upgradeable from 1.158 to 1.160
keyutils:amd64/testing 1.5.9-9 uptodate
libapparmor1:amd64/testing 2.11.0-2 uptodate
libdbus-1-3:amd64/testing *manually* upgradeable from 1.10.14-1 to 1.10.16-1
libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64/testing 2.4.74-1 uptodate
libdrm-dev:amd64/testing 2.4.74-1 uptodate
libdrm-intel1:amd64/testing 2.4.74-1 uptodate
libdrm-nouveau2:amd64/testing 2.4.74-1 uptodate
libdrm-radeon1:amd64/testing 2.4.74-1 uptodate
libdrm2:amd64/testing 2.4.74-1 uptodate
libegl1-mesa-drivers:amd64/testing 13.0.4-1 uptodate
libfdisk1:amd64/testing 2.29.1-1 uptodate
libgcrypt20:amd64/testing 1.7.6-1 uptodate
libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64/testing 13.0.4-1 uptodate
libglapi-mesa:amd64/testing 13.0.4-1 uptodate
libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64/testing 1.15-1 uptodate
libinput-bin:amd64/testing 1.6.0-1 uptodate
libinput10:amd64/testing 1.6.0-1 uptodate
libip4tc0:amd64/testing 1.6.0+snapshot20161117-5 uptodate
libjim0.76:amd64/testing *manually* upgradeable from 0.76-2 to 0.76-2+b1
libk5crypto3:amd64/testing 1.15-1 uptodate
libkrb5-3:amd64/testing 1.15-1 uptodate
libkrb5support0:amd64/testing 1.15-1 uptodate
liblz4-1:amd64/testing *manually* upgradeable from 0.0~r131-2 to 0.0~r131-2+b1
libmount1:amd64/testing 2.29.1-1 uptodate
libncurses5:amd64/testing 6.0+20161126-1 uptodate
libncursesw5:amd64/testing 6.0+20161126-1 uptodate
libpam-systemd:amd64/testing *manually* upgradeable from 232-15 to 232-18
libseccomp2:amd64/testing 2.3.1-2.1 uptodate
libselinux1:amd64/testing 2.6-3 uptodate
libsmartcols1:amd64/testing 2.29.1-1 uptodate
libssl1.1:amd64/testing *manually* upgradeable from 1.1.0d-2 to 1.1.0e-1
libsystemd0:amd64/testing *manually* upgradeable from 232-15 to 232-18
libtinfo5:amd64/testing 6.0+20161126-1 uptodate
libudev1:amd64/testing *manually* upgradeable from 232-15 to 232-18
libvulkan1:amd64/testing 1.0.39.0+dfsg1-1 uptodate
libwacom-common:all/testing 0.22-1 uptodate
libwacom2:amd64/testing 0.22-1 uptodate
libxfont2:amd64/testing 1:2.0.1-3 uptodate
linux-base:all/testing 4.5 uptodate
linux-kbuild-4.9:amd64/testing 4.9.6-3 uptodate
linux-libc-dev:amd64/testing 4.9.6-3 uptodate
mount:amd64/testing 2.29.1-1 uptodate
rpcbind:amd64/testing 0.2.3-0.5 uptodate
systemd:amd64/testing *manually* upgradeable from 232-15 to 232-18
systemd-sysv:amd64/testing *manually* upgradeable from 232-15 to 232-18
sysvinit-utils:amd64/testing *manually* upgradeable from 2.88dsf-59.8 to 2.88dsf-59.9
udev:amd64/testing *manually* upgradeable from 232-15 to 232-18
usb-modeswitch:amd64/testing 2.5.0+repack0-1 uptodate
util-linux:amd64/testing 2.29.1-1 uptodate
xserver-common:all/testing 2:1.19.1-4 uptodate
xserver-xorg:amd64/testing 1:7.7+18 uptodate
xserver-xorg-core:amd64/testing 2:1.19.1-4 uptodate
xserver-xorg-input-all:amd64/testing 1:7.7+18 uptodate
xserver-xorg-input-evdev:amd64/testing 1:2.10.5-1 uptodate
xserver-xorg-input-libinput:amd64/testing 0.23.0-2 uptodate
xserver-xorg-input-mouse:amd64/testing 1:1.9.2-1+b1 uptodate
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics:amd64/testing 1.9.0-1+b1 uptodate
xserver-xorg-input-wacom:amd64/testing 0.34.0-1 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64/testing 1:7.8.0-1+b1 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-cirrus:amd64/testing 1:1.5.3-1+b2 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev:amd64/testing 1:0.4.4-1+b5 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64/testing 2:2.99.917+git20161206-1 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64/testing 6.9.5-1+b2 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-mga:amd64/testing 1:1.6.5-1 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-neomagic:amd64/testing 1:1.2.9-1+b2 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64/testing 1:1.0.13-1+b1 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-openchrome:amd64/testing 1:0.5.0-3 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-qxl:amd64/testing 0.1.4+20161126git4d7160c-1 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64/testing 6.10.2-1 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-radeon:amd64/testing 1:7.8.0-1+b1 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-savage:amd64/testing 1:2.3.9-1 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion:amd64/testing 1:1.7.9-1 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-sisusb:amd64/testing 1:0.9.7-1 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-tdfx:amd64/testing 1:1.4.7-1 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-trident:amd64/testing 1:1.3.8-1 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-vesa:amd64/testing 1:2.3.4-1+b2 uptodate
xserver-xorg-video-vmware:amd64/testing 1:13.2.1-1+b1 uptodate
```

Comment: Include the output of `apt-cache policy` in your post (after running `apt update`).

Comment: ok, added to the post

Comment: Looks like you have mixed testing and stable. If you have ran an `apt-get upgrade` since adding testing to your sources, you are no longer running stable (jessie).

Comment: well, theoretically if I understand correctly kernel 4.9 - available only in testing repository, therefore I added testing repository, now when everything screw up I need to find a solution to a problem

Comment: No, newer kernels are also available in Jessie backports. You've got some weird pinning going on too, I think that's the main reason you can't install Skype's dependencies...

Comment: @StephenKitt So that is probably my right question, is how to fix pinning to good one that I can install dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

To install a `.deb` , you should use `gdebi` to solve the dependencies problem:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo aptitude update
wget -O skype-install.deb http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb
sudo gdebi skype-install.deb
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
skype
```

[Source](https://wiki.debian.org/skype)

> Problems starting Skype
>
> When starting Skype, a native 32 bit binary, in a 64 bit environment you might run into the following error and Skype refuses to start:
>
> ```
> ln -s /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
> ```

**Edit**

Remove/comment the `unstable` sources from your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Create a `/etc/apt/preferences` file with the following contents:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Run :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: No, this will not work, Already tried, get me -  Cannot install 'libqt4-dbus:i386'
I think Stephen Kit mention that it is probably some pinning problem.

Comment: @alex_mike Your kernel is installed from `backports` , Stephen and Jordanm are right about the sources.list and the pining

Comment: Yes, i'm already  has the same  /etc/apt/preferences file, it was on one of the forum, it is not helping me, I posted my source list.

Comment: @alex_mike Can you add the output of `apt-show-versions | grep testing`

Comment: added the output, it is a lot of packages, well I just need the intell driver to work with vulkan, the rest I don't need, so I probably need to downgrade some of them to stable versions, right?

Comment: You can safety install the newest intel driver from `backports`  (`xserver-xorg-video-intel`) the same version of package exit on testing. and keeping your system stable. A lot of mixed package ( stable + testing)  can break your system  anytime

Comment: can you help me do do it correctly, I don't want to remove packages and then mess up even more.

Comment: Change stable by testing on your sources list and on your APTpreferences too , remove `backports` then update and run `apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: I think that the first net-install is the `testing` release , is that right?

Comment: yes. I delete the backport  and testing. Sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade, don't reinstall anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54450/discussion-between-alex-mike-and-gad3r).